# Xcode excluding library from simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

In my Xcode iOS project, I need to work with a library that does not support simulator as a run destination. I`m only using it in a small part of the app, and I would like to exclude it from the simulator so that the app builds without it. 
I know I can add a separate target to the project and only add it to that target and build for simulator from another target that does not include the framework, but since I already have 4 targets, there would be a complete mess.

Is there some way to exclude libraries from the simulator without creating a new target?